# Импортирования в юнити

Tags: unity3d, unity3d-editor

Как правильно импортировать (к примеру пнг-шки интерфейса) по одному, т.е. каждая кнопка на отдельном файле, или все кнопки и панели в одном файле, может ли это как-то повлиять на занимаемую память? И как лучше делать что бы: качественее изображения - меньше занимаемой памяти?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Как правильно импортировать (к примеру пнг-шки интерфейса) по одному, т.е. каждая кнопка на отдельном файле, или все кнопки и панели в одном файле

В самом идеальном варианте все должно быть в одном файле. Но на практике в юнити оставляют это все в отдельных ресурсах. Склеенными оставляют в основном какие-то 2д анимации.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Простота кода чаще важнее того мелкого порфита от быстродействия, который ты получаешь от склейки ресурсов. А склейка ресурсов означает усложнение кода (нужно, ведь, еще что бы юнити понимал из какого куска изображения вытягивать нужное)

Если уж что-то и влияет на быстродействие, то, чаще всего, совсем не это в первую очередь.

> И как лучше делать что бы: качественее изображения - меньше занимаемой памяти?

Юнити не использует оригинальные изображения которые ты ему подсовываешь. Юнити сам конвертирует и пережимает файлы для себя. Ты лишь указываешь уровень сжатия(в настройках импорта ресурса).

Comment: Просто как я делал, у меня интерфейс (меню, настройки т.д.) в одном файле, просто разкинут по монтажным областям фотошопа (т.е. как в илюстраторе), при сохранении фотошоп просто склеевает все монтажные области в одно изображения и делает между ними некий отступ что бы было понятно где разделитель, может ли это тратить лишниюю память? т.к. у меня полно свободного места там.

Comment: проверь на практике. Возьми и сохрани файл в PNG. А потом возьми и удали 3-4 изображения кнопок из твоего изображения что бы там остались пустые места(фактически ты заменил изображения на эти самые отступы за которые ты переживаешь) и снова сохрани, но в другой файл. А потом попробуй сравнить вес файлов в байтах. Что-то мне подсказывает что вес уменьшится :) И если он уменьшится -- твои отступы роли не играют вообще никакой.

Comment: проверил - да, размер стал больше, что для PNG что для PSD. И тем более, если монтажные области будут (1) типо: 1 1 1 1 ENTER 1 0 0 0 то 0 0 0 0 тоже будет считать как пиксели.

Comment: Посмотри сюда: https://prnt.sc/m1a9gc -- картинка с большим разрешением занимает на треть больше(30 кб против 20 кб). Хотя она в 3 раза больше.То есть сохраняет в себе, фактически, 9 картинок более мелких. Ясно что изменяя разрешение картинок изменится и размер. Я тебе говорил про другое -- не уменьшить количество пикселей, а именно убрать несколько изображений твоих и сделать вместо них отступы.

Comment: сделал, то же самое, если убрать картинку с сделать отступы то размер не уменшился, понял что нужно все делать по одному, но еще возник вопрос, вот сделал я картинк 512х512, в проводнике занимает 85 кб, в юнити же 256 кб, сколько в итоге будет при релизе?  И еще заметил, сделал сетку из изображения (одинаковых) 3 на 5 512 на 512, понятно что должно занимать 512 * 3 х 512 * 5 = 1536х2560 = 3 932 кб, а занимает 9.6 при уменшеном размере второй стороны до 2048 - https://prnt.sc/m1alcl

Comment: 1. компрессию какую выбираешь при сохранении?) Без компрессии или максималку? 2. в резизе будет занимать в зависимости от настроек импорта. Я же не знаю какие ты выбираешь.

Comment: вот - http://prntscr.com/m1axhr , настройки импорта.

Comment: вон там внизу компрессор квалити -- нормал стоит
можешь распаковать скомпиленую апликуху и посмотреть сколько даный ресурс занимает места если тебе интересно)

Comment: конечно интересно, я за этим сюда и пришел, только вот из Edittor Log (в консоли) - Used Assets and files from the Resources folder, sorted by uncompressed size:
 9.6 mb  8.9% Assets/Main menu/AllIcons.png Какой тут 9.6 мб? если при размере 1536х2560 (уменшеном до 2048) размер на столько велик - https://prnt.sc/m1alcl

Comment: в ассеты входит далеко не только картинки, в ассеты входят еще и библиотеки компилируемые, аудио, файлы настроек и еще что-то. Если интересно что конкретно - смотри в документации. Ороме того PNG - это уже compressed. Uncompressed это bmp, а он знаимает значииительно больше png. И в оперативку, скорее всего(не уверен до конца), всегда выгружается bmp. Попробуй сохранить свою картинку в бмп и взвесить. Сколько выйдет?

Comment: bmp - 11.1 МБ, выше вы написали что в ассеты входят еще библиотеки и т.д. это я знаю, но в Editor Log пишет конкретно что входит и сколько весит, вот 9.6 mb - это суто одна картинка, почему так много? Вопрос тот же что и в предыдущем посте, почему так много весит при 1536х2560?

Comment: Uncompressed это bmp

Answer (score 1):

Заходите в настройки текстуры которую вы загрузили. Далее выставляете ей признак `Texture Type = Sprite (2D adn UI)`, `Sprite Mode = Mulitle` и заходите в [SpriteEditor](https://docs.unity3d.com/ru/520/Manual/SpriteEditor.html). В этом редакторе можно настроить разрезание атласа спрайта на отдельные изображения, задать их форму для физики и т.п. В проекте вы в последствии увидите все эти нарезанные изображения в качестве вложенных элементов вашей текстуры. Их можно использовать как текстуры для UI или как слайды анимации для 2D персонажа.